# Detect User Canceled Download with JS?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, session, cookies

I have a web page that lets users download an Excel document. The functionality is built mostly in jQuery and PHP.

There's a loading gif that overlays the screen after the user submits the request form. There's a JS interval that looks for a cookie that PHP sends along with the Excel document. As soon as the file downloads, JS can detect this cookie and remove the gif.

I'm having problems though if the user aborts the download. The gif isn't removed because the cookie is never received.

Is there a way to detect the "Cancel" browser action with JS? Or can I detect the cancellation with PHP's connection_aborted() function and then resend a new header with the required cookie?

Comment: I believe you cannot detect user connection abort.

Comment: The same header that tells the browser to put up the "Save" dialog is where the cookie is located, so it should already work properly.  (I know that that technique works for me whether or not the download is canceled.)

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies so far. @Pointy, the Cancel button I'm referring to is not the one in the Save dialog. I mean the Cancel button in the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to do a polling of some kind.

- 1 - Dispatch an ajax request to the server, tell the server to check if the connection is still in place.
- 1.1 - If the server returns a positive answer, wait N seconds and repeat #1.
- 1.2 - If server responds negatively, user has cancelled the download.